# How many large format LiFePO4 cells can be connected in series?

Tags: series, lifepo4

Is there any real reason why I couldn't connect **320** LiFePO4 cells in series (for a nominal 960Vdc)?

Or is there some limitations within the pouches inside the cells?

Like to see your thoughts!

Comment: Here's a thought that you may or may not like to see.  The fact that you have to ask this basic a question strongly suggests that it's [not a good idea](http://i.imgur.com/RrbJERx.jpg) for you to do 960V DC in practice (or anything above 48V).

Comment: I have no experience with such things. But have you ever seen a 1kV DC arc? Plasma is fairly conductive. I'm going to add two video URL's. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zez2r1RPpWY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaLSTnJE44o

Comment: If the protection circuit on an individual cell opens, it will be creating conditions similar to what you witnessed in those two videos, at least in terms of potential (if not amperage).

Comment: Firstly, I'm well aware that higher DC Voltages can arc as you mention. I was a welder in one former career. There are regular DIN-rail mounted circuit breakers that are rated for up to 1200V and 125Amps so that is not the issue. They have inbuilt arc suppressors, and aren't cheap. I've got two on my solar PV system, Voc is 850Vdc.

Comment: Talking with a battery manufacturer, they have used them in electric buses with a battery pack with 96 cells in series, 336V. So Nick, your 48V is way under what can be done. Protection circuits. Rather than disconnect an individual cell, we can monitor each individual cell and only react if any one cell goes under or over pre-defined limits, by turning off the load/charger. So back to the original question.......

Comment: Perhaps I should mention the potential application is large industrial UPS. Using 500Ah cells. I only ask because if able to operate at such higher voltages, I'd expect some improvement to overall efficiency from the inverter not having to step up/down the voltage so much.

Comment: It sounds like you have it well covered DJR, and that you don't need our help at all, put as many in series as you like. Let us know how that works out for you.

Comment: Maybe I can!? I've since found LG Chem's R1000 is 880Vdc x 60Ah, albeit with what is no doubt a fairly sophisticated BMS.

Comment: I thought this might have been a topic of interest for some at least. Just wanted to see if anyone had any experience or scientific knowledge they could share.

Comment: @DJR96 Nick Alexeev's suggestion of 48V was based on what's safe for an inexperienced user, not based on what's possible with the cells.

Comment: Think about it: the cells themselves don't "know" what the total voltage is. The limitations are entirely to do with construction safety. Tesla battery packs are just a lot 18650 cells in series up to 375V .. in a titanium crashproof case. I know it's offputting to get negative safety advice, but it's important.

Comment: So I guess it must come down to the physical construction of the cell pouches. Perhaps the spacing of the anode/cathode etc. And therefore the larger the cell design the higher the voltage can safely go. I guess larger clearances would reduce the rate it can transfer energy, but increase the capacity too. Something along those lines......

Comment: @DJR96 :: the pouch has nothing to do with maximum voltage.  I worked for a ultracap company where I designed a number of high-power high-voltage ultracap modules.  The pouch max voltage is ~200V but the maximum module voltage was easily ~1,500 V.  It's about the module design and assembly.  The pouch voltage "floats" between the negative and positive terminals of the cell.

Answer (score 2):

You will need:

1. A few million dollars for an engineering team to develop a good enclosure with all the spacing/creepage clearances/insulators.
2. A very sophisticated central BMS that can work across the full kV range.  This will likely require fiber optic insulation.
3. Good testing facility with very expensive battery testing equipment that works at 1 kV.
4. Full 40 cal PPE whenever you are close to the battery.

[image]

Mind you that Li cells come with built-in oxidant so firefighting is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly straightforward to design a system that works normally. Battery voltage = N cells * cell voltage.

What could there possibly be in the pouch that might object to this many cells in series? Nothing *per se*. However, in a 1000v battery, there is the possibility that you could have a potential difference of up to 1000v across any insulator. With cells that are designed for 4v operation, the cell manufacturer may, or may not, have anticipated the need for 1000v insulation.

That is your first job as the designer of the larger system. To design your battery so the insulation round cells does not see a voltage of more than the manufacturer specifies for the cell. If the manufacturer specifies perhaps 100v, then perhaps assembling the cells into sub-100v batteries, and balancing the voltage between batteries. If the manufacturer does not specify an insulation withstanding voltage, then you should not assume more than 48v. This is the voltage generally recognised by most electrical specification bodies below which you do not need to worry about insulation for shock prevention.

Next job is the BMS, to protect the cells from over charge and over discharge. It has to work over 1000v, but again that's fairly straightforward as it's expected behaviour. Use BMS chips, cascade them with suitable voltage isolation, and they should work.

I would expect that would take perhaps 10% of your design effort, to make the cells work as expected.

What should take 90% of your design effort is to anticipate, and guard against, unexpected behaviour. 1000v DC will sustain one heck'v'n'arc if there's an accidental open anywhere in the battery. Do you mitigate this by breakers that will break 1000v, shunts that will short the open, a bomb-proof box round the battery, or all three? An internal short that destroys a cell may have a similar problematic effect to an open.

A 1000v battery built from safe cells would be fairly dangerous. Built from, Li cells, which have a reputation similar to a hand grenade, you could expect it to be less safe.

How much research and testing will you have to do to check whether your mitigation systems have anticipated all failure modes, and can cope with all failure modes? That is your **big** problem. Boeing doesn't seem to have cracked it yet.

I guess if you are not targetting your battery system at aircraft, then you can afford a lower standard of safety. As a minimum, it would be nice if a cell failure did not result in loss of life to anyone standing within the blast radius. Then you can work up to not losing the vehicle or building it's in, and the pinnacle of safety would be not losing the battery itself.

If you survive your first major unanticipated fault, then let us know what you've learnt.

Comment: *targetting your battery system at aircraft* : see Boeing 787 lithium battery incidents.

Answer (score 1):

Each cell only sees its own voltage across it.  In theory you can stack a infinite number of cells in a line to get whatever voltage you want.  Of course you have to properly handle the high voltage end to end.  All cells in a physical line would be the least error prone.  If you fold the line of cells back and forth, then consider that there will be possible high voltages between nearby cells.  In your case you have 1 kV max, which isn't *that* hard to insulate.

The biggest issue will be using the cells effectively.  You need to quit drawing current when the weakest cell gets to the low point specified by the manufacturer.  Check the datasheet.  With that many cells in series, there will be significant energy left in the string when you have to stop due to the weakest cell.

Charging will also be a significant problem.  You have to stop charging when the first cell gets full.  Others could still be well below full.  After a few cycles, you will hardly have any room between discharging the lowest cell and charging the highest cell.  This is why strings of even just a few cells use *charge balancing*.  The voltage across every cell is measured, and a shunt is connected across the cells above the median.  This slows down their charging and lets the lower voltage cells catch up.